# GUI Tipping Table from Console Based Application

Tags: c#, user-interface

http://i49.tinypic.com/sl43th.png

I recently wrote a console based application that a low tip rate, high tip rate, a  max dinner price, etc..

Now I am supposed to make it into a GUI and base it off of a user's input rather than predefined variables. The picture above is what the final result should look like.

I don't understand how to go from console based to GUI.

For helping reasons-
The lowest tip rate textbox is labeled lTipRate
The lowest dinner price textbox is labeled lDinBox
The highest tip rate box is labeled hTipRate
The highest dinner price is labeled hDinPRice
The button is labeled calcTips

Everything for the most part has been done through console based and not GUI throughout this semester so I am having a really hard time converting to and from.

Could anyone explain how I would go about this?

Thank you so much.

Here is the code from the console based one.

```
    using System;
    public class TippingTable
    {
    public static void Main()
    {
    double dinnerPrice = 10.00;
    double tipRate;
    double tip;

    const double LOWRATE = 0.10;
    const double MAXRATE = 0.25;
    const double TIPSTEP = 0.05;
    const double MAXDINNER = 100.00;
    const double DINNERSTEP = 10.00;

    Console.Write("   Price");
    for(tipRate = LOWRATE; tipRate <= MAXRATE;
        tipRate += TIPSTEP)
        Console.Write("{0,     8}" , tipRate.ToString("F"));
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

    tipRate = LOWRATE;

    while (dinnerPrice <= MAXDINNER)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,     8}", dinnerPrice.ToString("C"));
        while (tipRate <= MAXRATE)
        {
            tip = dinnerPrice * tipRate;
            Console.Write("{0,     8}",tip.ToString("F"));
            tipRate += 0.05;
        }
        dinnerPrice += DINNERSTEP;
        tipRate = LOWRATE;
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Think of the difference between `GUI` and `console` the same as the difference between `procedural` and `OOP` approaches. the console only allows procedural `Console.Read()` and `Console.Write()` while a GUI is composed of several instances of several classes (such as `Labels`, `TextBoxes`, `ComboBoxes`, `Buttons`, etc) where you can call methods in them and modify their properties. And there's also the event-based stuff. You should do some research about all these concepts.

Comment: I know the labels, TextBoxes, etc... I just don't know how to use the for loop and everything with them.